# Warning Undefined array key in PHP

Tags: php, xampp

I have a problem when I try to use a variable from _POST ($ x), when I try to run the page I get a Warning Undefined array key.

```
<form name="f1" action ="test.php" method="POST">
1. Un SGBD es:<br>
<br>

<input type="radio" name="grupo" value="1"> Un conjunto de datos y programas <br>
<input type="radio" name="grupo" value="2"> Un lenguaje de programacion <br>
<input type="radio" name="grupo" value="3"> Igual a una base de Datos <br>
<br>
</form>
```

```
<?php
    $nota=0;

    $group = $_POST['grupo'];

    switch($group)
    {
        case 1:{
            $nota=$nota+20;
        }
    }
?>
```

Warning: Undefined array key "grupo" in ...

Pd: I am using XAMPP

Comment: When there is no `$_POST`, then you get that error.

Comment: Are you submitting to the same page? And for that matter, there is no submit button in the example you've posted to the question.